# Select records after 5 records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, records

I want to select records after first 5 records in a table. The table is getting updated with new records. I have displayed 5 new records `select top 5 * from table order by ID DESC`.

Now I want to Display another 5 records somewhere else in the page, what will be the query for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH tmp AS  
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.id) AS 'rn', a.* FROM table a)
SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE rn BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

Comment: @user2075460 Glad to hear it. You should mark it as the accepted answer then, by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM  [dbo].[4]   
ORDER BY [id] ASC 
OFFSET  5 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```